# How to get historic data including today

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

```
=GoogleFinance(A5,"close", TODAY()-500, TODAY())
```

This return data from yesterday. Any idea how to get the data from today ?

Answer (score 1):

note that today's data are not closed until tomorrow so for today you can only see actual data which may or may not be updated upon closing it